# Understanding REST create request url

Tags: java, spring, rest

What will be the url for creating an entity say `myEntity` through a rest url? `myEntity` has two parameter `name` and `description`. 
 Here is how rest controller looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response createJobType(MyEntity myEntity) {}
```

If it looks ok then how would `myEntity` parameters will passed through request url?
It's test class:

```
@Test
public void testShouldCreateMyEntity() {
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    entity.setName("Sample Name");
    entity.setDescription("Sample Description);
    String url = buildRequestURL("/create/"+entity).toUrl(); // Confused :(
}
```

Not sure if I should pass entity with URL. If not then how the entity would be passed?

Comment: Pass the parameters in the body, as form parameters or JSON or other content type. Note that since this is REST, your URLs shouldn't be verbs. Actions should be described by the HTTP methods. Create could be a POST or PUT.

Comment: You should send a POST request. POST requests usually pass the parameters in the request body, not in query string. You can pass the entity in XML or JSON format (I would prefer using JSON).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. Yes, I have create method as `POST`. Does url `create` represent a verb?

Comment: Yes, _create_ is a verb. `/entity` would make more sense in REST.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of testing your endpoint, and these tests might vary according to your needs.

For example, if authentication is required, or if HTTPS is required.

But supposing you don't need authentication and HTTPS is not used, you can test your endpoint with this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class RestClientTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;

        try {

            httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localaddressportetc.../create"); // <-- I suggest you change this to "entity" since this is what is being created by the POST

            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content-type", "application/json"));

            MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
            entity.setName("Sample Name");
            entity.setDescription("Sample Description");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String entityJSON = gson.toJson(entity);

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(entityJSON);
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(input);

            for (NameValuePair h : nvps)
            {
                httpPost.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try{
                response.close();
                httpClient.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```